# AngularJS - Change navigation menu based on user logged

Tags: angularjs

I am using SpringBoot and Angular JS for my web application and I would like to know a good way to change the navigation menu based on the user logged.

I was placing the navigation bar inside all the views but im sure there is a better way to do it.

User.class

```
@Entity
public class Usuario implements Serializable {
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Rol rol; -> This can be "UserA","UserB","UserC"
}
```

And my different navigation menus are

Navigation for UserA

```
<nav id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#/userA1">A1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/userA2">A2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/userA3">A3</a></li>
        </ul>
</nav>
```

Navigation for UserB

```
<nav id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#/userB1">B1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/userB2">B2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/userB3">B3</a></li>
        </ul>
</nav>
```

Navigation for UserC

```
<nav id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#/userC1">C1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/userC2">C2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/userC3">C3</a></li>
        </ul>
</nav>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For all nav add `ng-show` and control your rol. And you have set your rol to **$scope.role**

```
<nav id="nav" ng-show="role=='userA'">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#/userA1">A1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/userA2">A2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/userA3">A3</a></li>
        </ul>
</nav>
```

If you don't want to use ajax call;You can set $scope.role value on your jsp and when user changed result will be changed. You can use "JSTL" or "Jsp shortTag" shortTag example;

```
<nav id="nav" ng-show="<%=rol%>=='userC'">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#/userC1">C1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/userC2">C2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/userC3">C3</a></li>
        </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Shouldn't I add a controller to the nav div?

Comment: You need to create angular controller. Add this to <body ng-controller="">. Create function which calls your spring url and set rol to scope.role in this ajax call.

Comment: Okay, I will try it, I just have one question, if UserA logs out and UserB logs, will it automatically change the navigation bar or I do have to 'call' the controller again? Im really new to AngularJS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-show`, `ng-if` or `ng-switch`. Beter use ng-if or ng-switch as it doesn't create html for other roles and other users wont be able to see links for other roles if they do *inspect element*. ng-show will just hide only(adds the display:none style)

In controller get the role

### JS

```
$scope.role = $http.get("some url to get role");
```

### HTML

```
<nav id="nav" ng-switch='role'>
    <ul ng-switch-when='userA'>
        <li><a href="#/userA1">A1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/userA2">A2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/userA3">A3</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul ng-switch-when='userB'>
        <li><a href="#/userB1">B1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/userB2">B2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/userB3">B3</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul ng-switch-when='userC'>
        <li><a href="#/userC1">C1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/userC2">C2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/userC3">C3</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul ng-switch-default='userDefault'>
        <li><a href="#/userDefualt1">Default1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/userDefault2">Default2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/userDefault3">Default3</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Default is optional